# How to cast to a type alias in Go?

Tags: types, casting, go

See **[this playground snippet](http://play.golang.org/p/RynMln1E7c)**.

Relevant code:

```
type somethingFuncy func(int) bool

func funcy(i int) bool {
    return i%2 == 0
}

var a interface{} = funcy

func main() {

    _ = a.(func(int) bool)  // Works

    fmt.Println("Awesome -- apparently, literally specifying the func signature works.")

    _ = a.(somethingFuncy)  // Panics

    fmt.Println("Darn -- doesn't get here. But somethingFuncy is the same signature as func(int) bool.")
}
```

The first cast works, by explicitly declaring the type. But the second cast panics. Why? Is there a clean way to cast to a longer func signature?

Comment: `somethingFuncy` is *not* a type alias to `funcy(i int) bool`. It's a completely new type, which is defined as `funcy(i int) bool`. It's like if you define `type A struct {Foo string}` and `type B struct{Foo string}`. They're different.

Comment: tl;dr: A named type is always different from **any other type**. see type assertion doc: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions

Answer (score 92, accepted):

#### tl;dr

For type assertions (which you use) only the actual type matters. So `somethingFuncy` is only equal to `somethingFuncy` and not to `func(int) bool`.

#### Explanation

To start with, this has nothing to do with casting. There is no casting in go.
There are [type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and [type conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

You're dealing with a type assertion and are assuming that the same conditions hold
as for type **conversions**. I made the same mistake while reading your question but actually there is a huge difference in behaviour.

Suppose you have two types, say `int` and `type MyInt int`. These are convertible as they both
share the same underlying type (one of the conversion rules), so this works ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/aCTamybRQ4)):

```
var a int = 10
var b MyInt = MyInt(a)
```

Now, suppose `a` is not of type `int` but of type `interface{}` ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/Ww-yV3l3mX)):

```
var a interface{} = int(10)
var b MyInt = MyInt(a)
```

The compiler will tell you:

> cannot convert a (type interface {}) to type MyInt: need type assertion

So now we're not doing *conversions* anymore but *assertions*. We need to do this ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/cM_mCzaQ9S)):

```
var a interface{} = int(10)
var b MyInt = a.(MyInt)
```

Now we have the same problem as in your question. This assertion fails with this panic:

> panic: interface conversion: interface is int, not main.MyInt

The reason for this is stated in the [type assertions section](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) of the spec:

> For an expression x of interface type and a type `T`, the primary expression `x.(T)`
>   asserts that `x` is not `nil` and that the value stored in `x` is of type `T`. The notation 
>   `x.(T)` is called a type assertion.
>   **More precisely, if `T` is not an interface type, `x.(T)` asserts that the dynamic 
>   type of `x` is identical to the type `T`**.

So `int` must be identical to `MyInt`. The rules of [type identity](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) state that 
(amongst other rules):

> Two named types are identical if their type names originate in the same TypeSpec.

As `int` and `MyInt` have different declarations ([TypeSpecs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations)) they're not equal
and the assertion fails. When you assert `a` to `int`, the assertion works.
So what you're doing is not possible.

#### Bonus:

The actual check happens [in this code](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/iface.c?name=go1.1.2#312), which simply checks if both types are
the same, as expected.

Comment: i cannot understand `if their type names originate in the same TypeSpec`. Could you show me an example? thanks.

Comment: There are some examples in the [TypeSpec definition](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations). In the answer I used `MyInt` which has the TypeSpec `MyInt int`. Therefore, `MyInt` is equal to `MyInt` but not equal to `type MySecondInt int` as `MySecondInt int` is not equal to `MyInt int` (the name is different).

Comment: Great explanation. I was looking into creating an alias for a struct that was getting imported from another package. I was just doing `type TreeNode tree.Node`, but it was giving `need type assertion` error when struct members i.e., `Node.Left` was being assigned a value/address. This explanation gave me idea of how to actually alias, and now after changing `type TreeNode tree.Node` to `type TreeNode = tree.Node`, it working as expected. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17310#issuecomment-250932760 for `Two named types are identical if their type names originate in the same TypeSpec`. So you can define the same type name `X` in different part of the source code, and they are considered as different. playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/1HB_T6FA6Xq

Answer (score 33):

## **Update 2017:**

With type assertions in Go 1.9, you can simply add `=` where you define the type.

```
type somethingFuncy = func(int) bool
```

This tells the compiler that `somethingFuncy` is an alternate name for `func(int) bool`.

Comment: Note that if you do this, you won't be able to add functions to the new type, it will only be an alias. You'll get an annoying `cannot define new methods on non-local type` error. Or at least I did when I tried this with a custom type based on string.

Comment: Old comment on an old answer, but for posterity's sake: it totally works now, and you can add methods, and this is a pattern I'm using a lot

Comment: Still getting errors with go1.15: `cannot define new methods on non-local type`

Comment: @SamHughes: [No you can't](https://go.dev/play/p/m4fKvqExb77)

Comment: @NickMatteo, with the assertion being: "on go@latest, it is possible to first define a type which is an alias for a type defined in a different package, and then add methods on that aliased type.", I alias integer types to approximate enums, usually with a value() method that casts to the aliased type for comparisons. I know this is possible with go@1.16 and later, and I am surprised to hear that go@1.15 doesn't support the pattern. From https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23042, I see the line `@griesemer griesemer added this to the Go1.11 milestone on Dec 7, 2017`, and thumbs-up from Robert.

Comment: It is important enough to clarify that any such methods must be added in the same package that defines the aliased type, and that when done in the way I describe, you must cast instances of your aliased type back to the original type to use any of that type's methods.

Comment: @NickMatteo, dude, I just realized what y'all were doing wrong. It's humorously meta that this answer didn't become "bad syntax" till the feature launched in go@1.11, but the pattern `^type \w+ =` does not exist in the golang spec. Here: https://go.dev/play/p/uAyET19N3bb

Comment: @SamHughes: You don't seem to be aware of the distinction between a type alias (with an =) and a type declaration (without an =), but that distinction is the entire point of this question and answer.

Comment: @NickMatteo, I observe the distinction that you're clarifying, and that adding a type alias for a specific function signature gives unhelpful error messages during compilation, while declaring types, which is what I've been doing is something different, and does work. That's kinda frustrating but it answers why we're both continuing to say different things. With my prior note on golang spec description of this behavior, this could definitely be better documented.

Answer (score 8):

Just to complete nemo's awesome answer, note that while you can't jump directly from an interface (e.f., `interface{}`) of a given dynamic type (e.g., `int`) to another type (e.g., `type MyInt int`), you can do the two steps one after the other:

- assert that the dynamic type of your variable is what you expect it to be;
- convert the result of that assertion to the type of your choice.

Note that since the underlying type is, as its name implies, *dynamic*, it's a good idea to test if the type assertion succeeded or failed.
On the other hand, the type conversion correctness is enforced by the compiler.

Here is your playground snippet slightly modified: http://play.golang.org/p/FZv06Zf7xi

Answer (score 2):

I believe that type alias is what you want. Proposal is accepted and should be in Go 1.9. Ie.

`TypeSpec     = identifier [ "=" ] Type .`

References
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18130
https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/18130-type-alias.md