# Is it possible to convince the Golang compiler to accept `type Foo int` as an `int`?

Tags: go, zeromq

I'm using the `pebbe/zmq4` ZeroMQ bindings for Go, and I'm trying to develop higher level interfaces for my code that ZeroMQ implements in order to support mocking in my tests.

As an example of my question, the `zmq4.Socket` struct's `RecvMessage` function expects a `zmq4.Flag` as an argument. `zmq4.Flag` is simply an `int`, as defined by `type Flag int` in the Go bindings.

I'm trying to develop my interfaces without any dependencies on the ZeroMQ bindings, so I have an interface defined as:

```
type Socket interface {
    RecvMessage(int) ([]string, error)
}
```

When I try to use a ZeroMQ socket for this interface, I get an error stating `... have RecvMessage(zmq4.Flag) ([]string, error) want RecvMessage(int) ([]string, error)`.

Is there any way to handle this, or do I just need to bite the bullet and depend on the ZeroMQ bindings in my interfaces?

Comment: Does the user of the Socket interface need to know the zmq4 constants to use the interface?   If so, there's not much downside to importing zmq4 in your package.

Comment: Good point... I'm the only one that uses it, so importing zmq4 shouldn't be an issue. Essentially my curiosity is causing me to make things more difficult, as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to realize that `type Foo int` is a separate type not an alias.
See [How to cast to a type alias in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577423/how-to-cast-to-a-type-alias-in-go)

The only thing you can do to call RecvMessage with zmq4.Flag is to convert it to int.

```
var f zmq4.Flag = 1
RecvMessage(int(f))
```