# how do I implement custom struct tags AND be able to XML encode a map?

Tags: go

I have the following:

https://play.golang.org/p/ADX6H-bh0CU

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type xmlMap map[string]string

type xmlMapEntry struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Value   string `xml:",chardata"`
}

func (m xmlMap) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    if len(m) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    err := e.EncodeToken(start)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for k, v := range m {
        e.Encode(xmlMapEntry{XMLName: xml.Name{Local: k}, Value: v})
    }

    return e.EncodeToken(start.End())
}

func main() {
    type Family struct {
        Siblings map[string]string
    }

    type MyFamily struct {
        Siblings xmlMap `json:"siblings" xml:"siblings"`
    } 

    // In reality, "f" comes from a function in an outside package...e.g. "f := somepackage.Function()"
    f := &Family{
        Siblings: map[string]string{"bob": "brother", "mary": "sister"},
    }

    var m = &MyFamily{}
    *m = MyFamily(*f)

    x, err := xml.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(x))
}
```

The Family struct comes from an outside package. I created MyFamily struct in order to add json and xml tags. If I try to xml encode MyFamily then I get an error:

```
xml: unsupported type: map[string]string
```

This is easily resolved by implementing the custom XML marshaller that I have done.

This creates a separate problem. I have tried to simplify the example but "f" comes from a function in an outside package...e.g. "f := somepackage.Function()". When I try to Alias f to m I get the error:

```
cannot convert *f (type Family) to type MyFamily
```

This happens because Family has a map[string]string but MyFamily has xmlMap. Even though they are the same underlying type I get that error.

The question is, how do I implement my custom struct tags AND be able to XML encode a map?

EDIT:
This is a simple example and can just be resolved by

```
var m = &MyFamily{Siblings: f.Siblings}
```

Since there are MANY fields in both Family and MyFamily this is just inefficient and just wanted to know if there's a better way.

Comment: You have misunderstood how type conversions work. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577423/how-to-cast-to-a-type-alias-in-go

Comment: 1. No need for pointer in `var m = &MyFamily{}`, a simple `m := MyFamily{}` is good enough. 2. No need to _assign_ a Family to a MyFamily, just construct your MyFamily: `m := MyFamily{Siblings: f.Siblings}`. Done

Comment: You stated that "Even though they are the same underlying type I get that error" but this is _not_ true, they do _not_ share the same underlying type. It is true, that all the way down the memory layout of both type MyFamily and Family are the same, but their underlying types are different. The underlying type of MyFamily is `struct {Siblings map[string]string}` while the underlying type of Family is `struct {Siblings xmlMap}` . These are not the **same** type.

Comment: The underlying type of xmlMap is map[string]string so you can type convert between them. The concept of "underlying type" is not a recursive one: Underlying types is literally "the direct types are equal" (roughly; read the language spec for reference). See https://play.golang.org/p/Jxi4u_7R1Ex

Comment: @Volker "m := MyFamily{Siblings: f.Siblings}" There are a lot more fields than this example. I'd have to do that for every field, then? Seems there s/b a more efficient way.

Comment: No, there is not. Unless you make Family the underlying type of MyFamily and attach MarshalXML to Family itself. In this case the assignment from a family to a myFamily works (same underlying type) at the cost of a probably much more complicated MarshalXML method. You choose. (Note that copying a "lot more" fields is cheap, easy and simple to understand; I wouldn't bother.)