# Assigning named type to literal type value

Tags: go

Go newbie here. I am trying to assign an uint64  value to a variable of a named type with underlying type unit64. Compiler is unhappy and can't see the two types are exactly the same. What's the right way to do this?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math/rand"

type myType uint64

var x myType


func main() {
    x = rand.Uint64()
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

This throws compiler error:

```
./prog.go:12:4: cannot use rand.Uint64() (type uint64) as type myType in assignment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it `myType(rand.Uint64())`. Usefull links: [Type Assertion in Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and [Type Conversion in Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) as well as an excellent answer in this stack overflow question ["How to cast to a type alias in go"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577423/how-to-cast-to-a-type-alias-in-go)